# MobaXterm SSH config

Tags: ssh, mobaxterm

Can we make MobaXterm use Windows SSH binary and configuration ? I have the ./ssh/config which contains executables on the Windows OS once I use ssh. So if I try SSH using MobaXterm, it will not work because the it doesn't see the SSH config and the binaries on the main OS.

I tried linking the ./ssh/config, but the issue is with the executables within.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I only config use internal ssh agent and paste the path to private key
Setting >> SSH >> Use internal SSH agent...>>paste your ssh key path
https://i.stack.imgur.com/HK0VG.png